# Limit Adsense auto ads to certain div

Tags: html, css, ads, adsense

Is there a way to limit Adsense auto ads to certain element off the pages ?

I know that it’s possible to disable auto ads on certain pages but is there a special props that we can give to certain div in order to not have auto ads in it ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `#certain_div iframe { display: none; }`

Comment: There is no official way to do it, but approach suggested by @JanKyuPeblik is a possible workaround. The only change is that rather than hiding iframe you should hide ".adsbygoogle" element: `#certain_div .adsbygoogle { display: none; }`. That way ad will not be initialized and no ad request will be sent.

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau @J Thanks to both of you ! This should do the work, I’ll try it ! It would have been nice of them to propose an official way to do it...

Comment: Actually @Pol, if you go to AdSense site, ads tab and open Ad Preview of your site - you should see auto inserted ads and these ads contain a trash bin icon that allows you to block this placement. That is the official way to disable placements that you don't like. Does it work for you?

Comment: @MikitaBelahlazau oh nice ! Did not know this was a thing ! I’ll try it, thanks !